# Regular Expression to remove emoticons in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove emoticons from a piece of text, I looked at this regex from another question and it doesn't remove any emoticons. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong, or if there are better regex's for removing emojis from a string.

```
import re
myre = re.compile(u'('
u'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
u'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
 u'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+', 
re.UNICODE)

def clean(inputFile,outputFile):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as original,open(outputFile, 'w+') as out:
        for line in original:
            line=myre.sub('', line)
```

Comment: Can you provide the input file?

Comment: Is your text is plain ascii content?

Comment: Hi @ferkulat the text is a notepad txt file in utf-8, I have attached some sample data here. http://pastebin.com/uYUNk9R1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import re
myre = re.compile('('
'\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|'
'\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|'
'[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])+'.decode('unicode_escape'), 
re.UNICODE)

def clean(inputFile,outputFile):
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as original,open(outputFile, 'w+') as out:
        for line in original:
            line = myre.sub('', line.decode('utf-8'))
            print(line)
```

Comment: This worked when I removed line.decode('utf-8'), thanks @samuel !

Comment: It stopped working, I have no clue why, can you try the above code on a this text pastebin.com/uYUNk9R1 in a notepade doc ?

Comment: @Sorry: I just tested myself with `codecs.open(inputFile, 'r', "utf-8")` instead of your own `open` and with that, your original code works. After that, I tested Samuel's code ... and it *also* works. It is quite unusual for code to suddenly "stop working", which suggests the problem is not in Samuel's code. (It may be connected to "why did you have to remove a part of his answer?")

Comment: Did you test on the pastebin file I provided? I removed part of the answer because of a run time error I was receiving. Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: @Sorry: yes to both. You may want to specify what error you got.